# Maintain user data within the EJB application server memory

Tags: java, ejb, state

We work with a system using a web server accessing a clustered EJB 3.1 system. The user logs on and does some work over the day using the stateless session beans.

Besides the login data, we have new requirements, where we will store additional information about the user that is specific to the login, such as the user's mood, location, the color of the t-shirt, etc. Data that lives throughout the login, but is removed when the user logs off or logged off due to timeout.

We do not want to store anything in the database, provide the information with every call to the server, and other clumsy solutions. Neither - Of course! - should the data be stored in some static construction, threads cannot be used, etc. To us this feels quite straightforward, and that there should be a standard way to achieve this. But we fail to find an example. What do we do wrong?

I am a little surprised that there does not seem to be any built in feature to store this kind of data. The requirements as I described them above, are not unusual at all, and I have found them in most systems I have worked with. I have also found some non-satisfactory solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use stateless beans and you have a clustered system, you will have to use some sort of shared persistence layer to satisfy your new requirements. You can't save the data on a cluster instance (or you'll have to handle session stickiness).

I good, tested approach for session data is to use a simple (in terms of management) persistence solution such as [Redis](https://redis.io/). You can easily use this with a library like [jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis), without changing your existing database layer/model.

Comment: Thank! I will have a look into this.